# php array undefined index

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, indexing

I have searched google and the stack overflow forums and they repeatedly say use isset() to make sure the index is defined, however few of them give me an idea what to do if the index is not set.

Here is my simple code:

```
<?php
    $allStaff = $this->registry->getData('staff');
    $departments = array();
    foreach($allStaff as $staff){
        if(isset($departments[$staff['department']])){
            $departments[$staff['department']][count($departments[$staff['department']])] = $staff;
        }
        else {
            $departments[$staff['department']][count($departments[$staff['department']])] = $staff;
        }
```

An example of the idexing system is: $departments['Management'][0]['name/staff position/etc']

I have tried putting a $departments[$staff['department']] = 0 as I looked at some answers for other users, but it doesn't work and gives me more errors. Please help, thanks

Comment: i don't understand why you have the same line in if/else statement .. I'm not sure if i understand what is your purpose

Comment: *again* ? Show us your **exact** error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where it's going to give you problems is here:

```
count($departments[$staff['department']])
```

So you want to make sure that it has something compatible assigned to it, then you can use it:

```
if (!isset($departments[$staff['department']]))
    $departments[$staff['department']] = array();

$departments[$staff['department']][count($departments[$staff['department']])] = $staff;
```

PHP will by default handle sequential numeric indices for you, so you can simplify the above to (thanks to BNC for inspiration):

```
if (!isset($departments[$staff['department']]))
    $departments[$staff['department']] = array();

$departments[$staff['department']][] = $staff;
```

Just a note that your code has a pattern like `P[Q[i]][j] = Q`, will work okay, just don't often see that.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you are trying to do here.  My guess is you want to count how many staff members are in each department.  If my guess is wrong, please state your objective in English (not code).  If my guess is correct, ...

```
$allStaff = $this->registry->getData('staff');
$departments = array();
foreach($allStaff as $staff){
    if( !isset($departments[$staff['department']]) ) {
        $departments[$staff['department']] = 0;
    }
    $departments[$staff['department']] += 1;
}
```

UPDATE: Wait, I think I just figured it out (I was misled by the use of `count()` when `[]` is sufficient to append to an array).  I'm now guessing you want staff members grouped by department, ...

```
$allStaff = $this->registry->getData('staff');
$departments = array();
foreach($allStaff as $staff){
    if( !isset($departments[$staff['department']]) ) {
        $departments[$staff['department']] = array();
    }
    $departments[$staff['department']][] = $staff;
}
```